# Возможно ли обращаться к woocommerce напрямую, без сервера и аутентификации?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, http, api, rest

Здравствуйте, в woocommerce никак не могу найти способа работы с плагином без аутентификации (только get запросы нужны), возможно ли как-то напрямую с клиента получить информацию с сервера? Если нет, возможно есть другие CMS с хорошо реализованным REST АРІ, который можно для интернет-магазина использовать напрямую?

Comment: WooCommerce имеет полнофункциональный и хорошо документированный REST API.

Comment: И как это - работать с магазином без  сервера?

Comment: @KAGG Design просто получать с сервера с woocommerce json и выводить его?) магазин самый примитивный, даже скорее витрина, ничего кроме get запросов не надо

Comment: Нельзя обращаться к серверу без сервера))). REST API вернёт json.

Comment: @KAGG Design эм... мне кажется вы что-то себе не то надумали, конечно сервер есть, но мне надо получить с этого сервера ответ без аутентификации, без участвия сервера. Это отдельное от сервера приложение, на другом хостинге и т.д.

Comment: Прежде чем давать глубокомысленные комментарии, разберитесь, как работает REST API. Запрос на СЕРВЕР, где установлен WordPress и WooCommerce посылается через curl или прямо в адресной строке браузера, например: https://fibotelecom.ru/wp-json/wc/v2/products/?consumer_key=ck_110b8e0d3b00b20119466737febe679793995a08&consumer_secret=cs_da94473934fc3e86aac93f9d7df8e06bfbe7204b В запросе должны быть указаны consumer_key и consumer_secret, сгенерированные в настройках WooCommerce.  Запрос такого вида из адресной строки работает только через https.

Comment: Этот запрос принимается на СЕРВЕРЕ apache или nginx, который запускает php, тот стартует WordPress и WooCommerce. WooCommerce лезет в базу mysql и возвращает ответ в json. Ну и как это все делать БЕЗ СЕРВЕРА?

Comment: Мне надумывать нечего, в отличие от вас, я могу привести работающий пример. Пройдите по ссылке выше и увидите json, который вернул REST API WooCommerce.

Comment: @KAGG Design Хорошо, приведу я пример: есть сервер с будущем интернет-магазином на woocommerce (или, возможно, другой CMS), который будет продавать товары разного формата. Для некоторых отдельных категорий товаров нужно сделать отдельные приложения, для которых будет проводиться рекламная кампания и т.д. Они планируются делаться на другом хостинге и домене, это совершенно другие приложения, в которых хотелось бы обойтись исключительно клиентской стороной (получить прямой get запрос с сервера с woocommerce и исходя из него рендерить содержимое сайта). Но загружаться все должно на 1м сервере.

Comment: @KAGG Design приятно что вы взяли так близко к сердцу мою проблему, но все же, попрошу перечитать еще раз вопрос, если есть желание конечно

Comment: Ну так я же дал вам пример, как вообще через браузер сделать запрос и получить в ответ json. В чем проблема сделать такой get на клиенте?

Comment: @KAGG Design в аутентификации

Comment: ага, все, вижу, просто передать токкен в юрл, спасибо, не заметил такой возможности

Comment: Да, только учтите - это не прокатит с http, только https. Я пробовал.